# Compare 1st element of 1D list with 2D list and add the second element if found

Tags: python

There are two lists - one 1D list and one 2D list in this format:

```
a=['1','2','3','4']
b=[['1','a'],['1','z'],['2','c'],['4','r'],['4','d']]
```

Expected output:

```
[['1':'a','z'],['2':'c'],['3':'not found'],['4':'r','d']]
```

The logic is that we need to take each element of the list 'a' and compare it with the first element of list 'b'. If found, then add it (it can come multiple times, add all of them). If not found, add 'not found' in front of it.

My attempt:

```
x=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(b)):
                if (a[i]==b[j][0]):
                        x.append([a[i],b[j][1]])


  result=OrderedDict()

for k,v in x:
        if k in result.keys():
                result[k].append(v)
        else:
                result[k]=[v]
result=["{}\t{}\r\n".format(k, ",".join(v)) for k,v in result.items()]
```

The problem with my code is that it doesn't print 'NOT FOUND' if there are no match case.
If you have any other better option instead of looping multiple times, please suggest.

Comment: Slight problem: your ‘expected out’ is not valid syntax, and certainly doesn’t represent a list of dictionaries.. Please fix.

Comment: @barny sorry. I've added few lines so the expected output is fine now.

Comment: Err no that isn’t valid:  suggest rather than making it up that you actually try that syntax see if Python accepts it.

Comment: Let’s be specific - the “expected output” isn’t a valid repr of a list of dictionaries - it isn’t valid python syntax for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a dictionary for the elements of b

```
from collections import defaultdict
b_dict = defaultdict(list)

for i in b:
    b_dict[i[0]].append(i[1])

result = []
for a_i in a:
    temp = [a_i]
    if(b_dict[a_i]):
        temp.extend(b_dict[a_i])
    else:
        temp.append('not found')
    result.append(temp)
```

This would give the output

```
[['1', 'a', 'z'], ['2', 'c'], ['3', 'not found'], ['4', 'r', 'd']]
```